# What is the Query Of Percentage?

Tags: database

What is the code of percentage in database?

If I have a table in database, I want that code, who show me %, that how many percent record of data in a table?

Comment: i want querry to apply on database

Answer (score 0):

SELECT group_name, employees, surveys, COUNT( surveys ) AS test1, 
        concat(round(( surveys/employees * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
    FROM a_test
    GROUP BY employees

Comment: i dont understand you answer

Comment: If i have a table "CitizenDetail",
in this table i have a 450 records, what is the querry to find percentage of 450 records,I want that querry,who show me %,That how many percent record of data in a table?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT concat(round((count(id)/450*100),2),'%') as per FROM `CitizenDetail`

for getting percentage you always need two field one is total number and second which fields you want percentage.